# Float increments precision problems with UI

Tags: c++

Here is my problem, I have several parameters that I need to increment by 0.1.
But my UI only renders x.x , x.xx, x.xxx for floats so since 0.1f is not really 0.1 but something like 0.10000000149011612 on the long run my ui will render -0.00 and that doesn't make much sense.  How to prevent that for all the possible cases of UI.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  Why would your UI display `0.1f` as `"-0.00"`?

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't use a float... if you want 0.1 to be exact, use an integral type.

Comment: @Oli it isn't 0.1 is the increment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know that your floating point value will always be a multiple of 0.1, you can round it after every increment to make sure it maintains a sensible value. It still won't be exact (because it physically can't be), but at least the errors won't accumulate and it will display properly.

Instead of:

```
x += delta;
```

Do:

```
x = floor((x + delta) / precision + 0.5) * precision;
```

**Edit:** It's useful to turn the rounding into a stand-alone function and decouple it from the increment:

```
inline double round(double value, double precision = 1.0)
{
    return floor(value / precision + 0.5) * precision;
}

x = round(x + 0.1, 0.1);
```

Answer (score 6):

Use integers and divide by 10 (or 1000 etc...) just before displaying.  Your parameters will store an integer number of tenths, and you'll increment them by 1 tenth.